# Use data from Firebase in React Native SectionList. Problems with structure of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to show my data from Firebase in a React Native [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist). I have some Events to show to the user in a list.

Right now I show them in a FlatList but I want to show the Events to the user in sections by each day. This means I have to restructure the code that comes form my firebase-database.

The Structure that I need looks like this:

```
[
    {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
    {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
    {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
]
```

(From the React Native docs:)

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  sections={[
    {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
    {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
    {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
  ]}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```

This is how I get the data from my database:
(In my database I have informations to the events and the timestamp for each event)

```
firebase.database().ref(`/userEvents/${uid}/`).orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(now)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    thisArr = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      thisArr.push(child.val());
    });
    dispatch({
      type: GET_EVENTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: thisArr
    });
  });
```

I'm sitting on this problem for some hours now and can't figure out what might be the best way to provide this Data-Structure. I tried something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/userEvents/${uid}/`).orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(now)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    thisArr = [];
    const dayData = {
      title: '',
      data: []
    }; //contains title '', data []
    const data = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      const timestamp = child.val().timestamp;
      const date = moment(timestamp).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      if (dayData.title === date) {
        dayData.data.push(child.val());
      } else {
        dayData.title = date;
        dayData.data.push(child.val());
      }
      thisArr.push(child.val());
    });
    dispatch({
      type: GET_EVENTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: thisArr
    });
  });
```

The problem here is that I have to save every `dayData` in another array and I don't know how to achieve this. I don't really think this is a good solution either. It would be great if somebody has an idea how I could achieve this structure.

Comment: The data in your first snippet `{[ ... ]}` is not a valid object.

Comment: I just copied the first snippet from the React Native docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist)

Comment: @Tholle, probably that appears as a JSX prop, which have to be wrapped in `{}` like that.

Comment: @CRice Yes, you are right. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code almost works. You just have to make sure that you are creating a whole new `dayData` object each time the day (`title`) changes:

**Example**

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`/userEvents/${uid}/`)
  .orderByChild("timestamp")
  .endAt(now)
  .on("value", snapshot => {
    const result = [];
    let dayData = { title: "", data: [] };

    snapshot.forEach(child => {
      const timestamp = child.val().timestamp;
      const date = moment(timestamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

      if (dayData.title === date) {
        dayData.data.push(child.val());
      } else {
        dayData = { title: date, data: [child.val()] };
        result.push(dayData);
      }
    });

    dispatch({ type: GET_EVENTS_SUCCESS, payload: result });
  });
```

Comment: Awesome, now it works! Somehow I didn't see that last step. Thank you again so much for your help!